# Struts HeaderAction Class?

Tags: struts

When I go to the struts [`Action` api page](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/api/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html) , I can see all the subclasses of action class like `DynamicAction`, `IncludeAction` etc.
but I can't see `HeaderAction` from JOrganizer (http://jorganizer.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/juniverse/jorganizer/portal/HeaderAction.html)

Why it is so? Is it because it has been developed by community other than apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right... In fact, the javadoc program which generates the documentation is not aware of the other products. If you develop a class based on the Action class provided by Apache (in your own project), you will not see the Apache documentation updated.

By the way, Struts is now in version 2 since a (very) long time...